# Azure webjobs "invalid container name" intermittent error

Tags: azure, runtime-error, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

I've been writing a webjob with a blob watch (like http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx)

from time to time and without warning, I receive "invalid container name" exceptions from the line

```
host.RunAndBlock();
```

Despite not changing the container name in App.config, and while every other method of accessing the blob storage works.

Here's a stack trace for anyone who cares to go through it:

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0x17bc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at BarcodeJob.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Nik\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BarcodeJob\BarcodeJob\Program.cs:line 34
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

---

and the error message

```
System.FormatException: Invalid container name: 
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.BlobClient.ValidateContainerName(String containerName)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.CloudBlobPath..ctor(String blobInput)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.LogRow.ToPath()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.BlobLogListener.<GetRecentBlobWrites>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.BlobListener.Poll(Action`1 callback, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.Listener.PollBlobs(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.Listener.Poll(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.Worker.Poll(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.JobHost.RunAndBlock(CancellationToken token, Action pauseAction)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.JobHost.RunAndBlock(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.JobHost.RunAndBlock()
   at BarcodeJob.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Nik\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BarcodeJob\BarcodeJob\Program.cs:line 30
```

Comment: This looks like a crash from the middle of the SDK's blob listening code. Do you have other things running against that storage account that may be creating / deleting containers? Maybe that's tripping up the blob listener. 
It looks like containerName is empty or whitespace. When this happens, do you by chance know what the blobInput parameter is to the CloudBlobPath..ctor()?

Comment: The only other entity running is the Azure storage viewer, so no -nothing is creating or deleting containers.  
  
I did have the job copying and then deleting the blob from a CloudBlockBlob object. Although I tested with that code commented and still had this issue.  
  
here's my call with the blobinput param:  
  
     public static void RunNewUpload( [BlobInput("input/{name}.pdf")] Stream input, String name, [BlobOutput("output/{name}.pdf")] Stream output){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a bug report than an actual question... So there's not a specific question to answer here, but I can confirm that callstack is certainly incriminating that it's a bug in the WebJobs SDK. We've filed a bug and expect to fix it in the Alpha 2 release. The releases are done via nuget, so Alpha 2 will show up at: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.Host

Comment: (new to .net/azure) where in the callstack do you see said incrimination?

Comment: the callstack is showing frames in MS.WindowsAzure.Jobs, which is the assembly for the WebJobs SDK.